# Angular 2 Router: Navigating to other components

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Given the root routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'users',
                loadChildren: './pages/users/users.module#UsersModule'
            }
        ]
    },
    {path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '/login'}
];

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and the users routing module

```
const usersRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: UsersComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'admittances', component: AdmittancesComponent},
            {path: 'admittance/:id', component: AdmittanceDetailComponent}
        ]
    }
];

export const usersRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(usersRoutes);
```

i want to navigate from the `AdmittancesComponent` to the `AdmittanceDetailComponent`.

But, instead of using

```
this._router.navigate(['admittance', id]); // ERROR
```

i rather have to use

```
this._router.navigate(['users/admittance', id]); // WORKS
```

Can somebody explain why the first example is not working and why the second one fixes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following link is from the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation

For relative routing using the .navigate, you need syntax like this:

```
this.router.navigate([crisis.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple 
The appRoutes is the main route , the users route is a child of your Main Route .
Since you defined the name of the path in your appRoutes as 'users'  , that's going to be your first url parameter so  domain.com/users/childRoutes ...

Now as you have defined the child called admitance thats going to be prefixed by your parent Route  users /  so domain.com/users/admitance

It would have worked the first statement if you would have defined the route 'admitance' in your appRoutes